# Active Admin won't redirect to login for unauthorized user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin

When I try to access `localhost:3000/admin`. I just get a message "You need to sign in or sign up before continuing.". I am expecting to be redirected to the login page if I am not currently logged in. However, if I access `localhost:3000/admin/login` I see the login page and it works as expected.

My `active_admin.rb` config file is in its default state.

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure, but you could add this to your routes file just above the devise line. You might risk a redirect loop though..

```
get '/admin', to: redirect('/admin/dashboard')
root :to => 'admin/dashboard#index'
```

But it depends on how you want your application to behave. What happens if you access `localhost:3000/` ?

Comment: I removed all the code in the routes except the 2 lines in my post. `localhost:3000/` displays the default rails page. "Yay! You’re on Rails!"

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have some kind of exception handler catching the exception in your `ApplicationController` masking the proper redirect behavior

Comment: I removed all the code i had in the `ApplicationController`, the same thing happens.

Comment: That is odd, Can you verify this line `config.authentication_method = :authenticate_admin_user!` is present in the `active_admin` initializer file. Also can you post the server log for the request when you try to access `localhost:3000/admin` when not signed in.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, it ended up being that I had this setup:

```
# config/devise.rb
config.warden do |manager|
  manager.failure_app = CustomDeviseFailureApp
end

# lib/custom_devise_failure_app.rb
class CustomDeviseFailureApp < Devise::FailureApp
  def route(scope)
    :root_url
  end
end
```

once i removed that, all fixed.

Answer (score 0):

- add this line to application controller

```
  def authenticate_admin_user!
    if admin_user_signed_in?
      admin_root_path
    else
      new_admin_user_session_path
    end
  end
```

- activeadmin will call this method whenever you try to access `/admin`